# AngularJs dynamic orderBy expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Below is the code. I have nested ng-repeat and a field that has sum of all other fields.

```
<div class="animate margin-top" >
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center"  ng-repeat="data in leaderBoardData | orderBy: 'getTotal($index)'" style = "padding: 10px;" class= "md-padding">
            <section class="text-center width-20"><a>{{data.handleName}}</a></section>
            <section class="text-center width-20" ng-repeat="score in data.score track by $index">{{score}}</section>
            <section class="text-center width-20">{{getTotal($index)}}</section>
        </div>
</div>
```

So I want to sort it according to the dynamic field `getTotal($index)`. How should I do it? the above orderBy is not working.

Below is code for `getTotal()` function

```
$scope.getTotal = function (index) {
    var total = 0
    $scope.leaderBoardData[index].score.forEach(function (score) {
        total = total + score
    })
    return total
}
```

Below is leaderboardData

```
var leaderBoardData = [ { handleName: 'xyz', score: [1,2,3] },{ handleName: 'acc', score: [4,5,6] } ]
```

Comment: you want to sort it by 'total' properties?Please share the sample 'leaderBoardData ' structure

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes ! by total properties. Will edit and put the code

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN check out the data !

Comment: you want to sort the data by score?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN total score

Comment: first thing , there is no property with name  total score.You returning total score which is number.How you will sort it?.I am still not able to identify what you want to achieve.

Comment: you want to show the data by ASC or DESC order?

Comment: See I have a array of scores for each users ! I need to ad them and sort them according to the total score. I did some manipulation and added the totalScore field in the array and now its working ! But I wanted to know if I can sort with dynamic fields in ng-repeat.

Comment: sort them according to the total score. means?

Comment: Well you can do business in your controller and then do ng-repeat in template

Comment: Yup I did that when I was not able to make it work ! Check the other ans it is now working !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove the quotes for orderBy expression, so angular knows it's a function, you don't need to explicitly pass $index as an argument.
2. you need to change this `{{getTotal($index)}}` to `{{getTotal(data)}}` as data is already iterated in here.

so, basically:

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {

  $scope.leaderBoardData = [{
    handleName: 'xyz',
    score: [4, 5, 6]
  }, {
    handleName: 'acc',
    score: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    handleName: 'acFc',
    score: [1, 2, 4]
  }];

  $scope.getTotal = function(index) {
    var total = 0;
    // also change to index as array already passed to function
    index.score.forEach(function(score) {
      total = total + score;
    })
    return total;
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl" class="animate margin-top">
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center" ng-repeat="data in leaderBoardData | orderBy: getTotal" style="padding: 10px;" class="md-padding">
        <section class="text-center width-20">
          <a>{{data.handleName}}</a>
        </section>
        <section class="text-center width-20" ng-repeat="score in data.score track by $index">{{score}}</section>
        <section class="text-center width-20">
          <!-- change is here -->
          {{getTotal(data)}}
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I posted the array data !

Comment: Working ! :D Thanks !  so I was wrong in passing function in orderby? getTotal() ?

Comment: no orderby takes function as well, but you wrapped it with single quotes which according to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy it thinks it's a string

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that $scope.leaderBoardData isn't an array (it's an object of objects), and the orderBy filter only works with arrays. If you make $scope.leaderBoardData an array, it will work

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're not using forEach correctly.

```
    $scope.getTotal = function (index) {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.leaderBoardData,function(score,index){
        total = total + score
    })
    return total;
}
```

Try this and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way.
HTML

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center"  ng-repeat="data in leaderBoardData | orderBy: 'totalScore'" style = "padding: 10px;" class= "md-padding">
            <section class="text-center width-20"><a>{{data.handleName}}</a></section>
            <section class="text-center width-20" ng-repeat="score in data.score track by $index">{{score}}</section>
            <section class="text-center width-20">total score={{data.totalScore}}</section>
        </div>
```

JS :

```
$scope.leaderBoardData =  [ { handleName: 'xyz', score: [111,21,3] },{ handleName: 'acc', score: [14,5,16] } ];

     $scope.leaderBoardData.forEach(function(oneRecord,key){
        var total=0;
        oneRecord.score.forEach(function(oneEle,key){
            total = total + oneEle

        })
        oneRecord.totalScore = total;

     })
```

Comment: Yup I tried it this way ! But I think this is not the right way to do it when we can use angular functionality  !